# JQuery, variable inside function not recognized by action

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, methods

Foremost, let it be known that I am complete n00b at jQuery.

Second, I can't find any specific information regarding this issue anywhere, which is why I'm now finally posting this question.

Lastly, the incredibly strange and therefore frustrating thing about this issue that I'm having is that I'll get the code working, then step away from my computer for a bit to do something else, and when I come back suddenly the code no longer works.

Here is the code, which I have stored in an external file and referenced from the HTML:

```
    var adjPad = (function() {
        var ht = $('#contactinfo').height();
        $('.content p:last').css({'padding-bottom':ht});
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){adjPad();});
    $(window).resize(function(){adjPad();});
```

This will not do anything, as if the variable **ht** does not exist.

However, if I change the value of **'padding-bottom'** to, say, **XYZ + 'px'**, the code will indeed recognize that value and adjust the padding accordingly.

I'm so incredibly perplexed. Any help will be appreciated immensely!!

**As per requested, here is all of the relevant HTML:**

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="base.js"></script>
...
   <div class="content">
      <h1>HISTORY</h1>
      <p></p>
   </div>
...
   <div id="contactinfo">
      <div id="contactinfocontainer">
         <div id="left">
            <ul>
               <li></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
...
      </div>
   </div>
...
```

Thanks for all of the responses so far!!

**SOLVED!**

The issue is compatibility of across browsers.

**`'margin-bottom'`** works for Chrome.

**`'padding-bottom'`** works for Edge, Firefox, and Waterfox.

Happy coding!

Comment: Print the value of ht to console, what does it say? Also, did you try ht + 'px'

Comment: I ran his code in jsFiddle, and it logs the correct height, just try what @EricGuan said and add ht + 'px'.

Comment: Would you be able to add the relevant `HTML` to your question so we can see exactly what might be going wrong on that end in case your jQuery doesn't match up correctly?

Comment: I've also tried using **ht + XYZ + 'px'** and it only recognizes **XYZpx**.

I'm sorry, but I don't know how to print the value of **ht** from the console, but I'll learn how to do that right after I finish eating this garlic bread :)

Comment: Add this line: `console.log(ht);`

Comment: Thanks so much<33 Here is the output: **Uncaught ReferenceError: ht is not defined**

Comment: @ZachPerkitny **Uncaught ReferenceError: ht is not defined (anonymous function)**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96102/discussion-on-question-by-user2230470-jquery-variable-inside-function-not-recog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is compatibility across browsers.

**`'margin-bottom'`** works for Chrome.

**`'padding-bottom'`** works for Edge, Firefox, and Waterfox.

I hope this helps somebody in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Long time since not using jQuery, but i think height() will give you a number.

So try to pass ht+'px'

As css is intended to be made up of strings.

Furtermore jQuery.height() gives you a parsed css height, so if you are using % in your style sheet there will be a bug. In this scenario consider to get the object boundingbox and get height out from there.

This should be how to get the BB.

```
$(...).getBoundingBox().height()
```

JQuery parse CSS in line, so gives u problems with % and is sensitive to different browsers as well as the .height() is available only when the document is generated and then vanish. The BB interact dorectly with the rendering engine that converts % to px and arrange the elements in the page. So this will allways give you the real position of any object. (Inside the browser)

Comment: I tried that already. No dice unfortunately!

Actually, the **height** of **#contactinfo** is a **%**, but I've already had the jQ code working despite this. I'm not sure why it keeps randomly crapping out on me.

Object boundingbox?!

Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Jquery height method returns height in number.

```
var ht = $('#contactinfo').height(); //returns height in number
```

But your padding value needs to be in `px` so change the code to the following line and it should work:

```
$('.content p:last').css({'padding-bottom':ht+'px'});
```

Comment: Everyone is pointing out that you really should declare what unit you are requesting by specifying `ht + 'px'`. However, by default jQuery assumes you are referring to pixels, so this is not your issue (but still, specify your unit). https://jsfiddle.net/m0q0r9wy/

Comment: @jpschroeder I'm looking for a % output since the height of #contactinfo is a % and therefore I want padding-bottom to also be a %.

Comment: Well, careful with that. In CSS the padding % is based on the *width* of the element, and a percent of your `p:last` would be relative it its parent, which is not the same as `#contactinfo`'s parent. I'm pretty sure you really are looking for a `px` value.

Comment: So you should tell it earlier... then you need simply to read css   $(  ).css('height');

Comment: @jpschroeder Yeah, actually, my bad. I was in the middle of eating, so I really wasn't able to focus on my response. It really doesn't matter which unit the output is, but a **pixel** output should suffice. Further, I printed the definition of **ht** with the command **console.log(ht);** and the browser is responding with this: **Uncaught ReferenceError: ht is not defined (anonymous function)**

Comment: I would recommend that you watch some tutorials online, and read some articles and documentation.

Comment: @ZachPerkitny Yeah, I have been. This was literally the first piece of JS I ever wrote. I knew absolutely nothing about JS a few days ago.